# Ubuntu Server 16.04 Boot Issues

Tags: 16.04, boot, server

I had Ubuntu Server 16.04 running on a PC in my home for over a year now. Today, I decided shut it down, take out the hard drive, put in a new hard drive, and install a new copy of Ubuntu Server 16.04 to test something.

After finishing testing, I shut down the computer and put the original hard drive back into the computer, but when booting, it now says:

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key
```

Whats going on here?

Comment: Did you disconnected the new hard drive before turning back old hard drive? It seems your computer "renamed" old hard drive to sdb, instead of sda.

Comment: I simply shut down the computer with "sudo shutdown" then took out the new hard drive, and put in the old hard drive, and pressed the power button. If this were the problem, how would one fix it?

Comment: This message comes from your BIOS, (ie. computer hardware/firmware). The fix is also done in hardware/bios/firmware; off-topic I suspect here because its not an Ubuntu issue, but look in your BIOS setup  (AHCI etc)

Comment: This hard drive with ubuntu worked perfectly on this computer for 1 year and 4 months with zero downtime before swapping the hard drive and installing ubuntu on it. Would a ubuntu installation change the bios settings? if so, then it is a ubuntu issue. What would it have changed?

Comment: Probably when you changed hard drives, the order boot at BIOS was affected. Look if the hard drive is present and enabled at BIOS settings.

Comment: I've tried every possible combination of boot order Heres a picture of the boot settings. [link](http://shufordtech.com/prob/1.jpg)

Comment: Does the new drive still boot up properly?

Comment: No, i just tried that and it also doesn't boot up now with the same message on the screen as the image posted in the first post

Comment: Try re-inserting the new drive, putting the old drive in an external enclosure, and use the BIOS menu to boot from the old drive.  Does that work? leave a comment @Fabby to reach me.